# Alternative tuple iteration using constexpr

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

I want to write a function which kind of iterates over a `std::tuple<...>`. The iteration itself won't produce any problems regarding the tuple's template types, because '...' have the same types (like int, int, int, ...). I implemented already a working function 'Foo' with a helper struct 'Helper' using template metapgrogramming – everything is fine.

But when I want to implement an alternative version, using a constexpr function 'helper', the compiler (g++ 5.2.0) gets stuck in an infinite loop of error messages. From what I can get from these messages, the 'position' template parameter is instantiated as ridicilously big (== 4294967245) instead of (== 1). I tried to get both versions as close in syntax and nomenclature as possible.

**Minimal example**

```
#include <tuple>
// template metaprogramming version
template
<class T, std::size_t position>
struct Helper{
    static int
    help(T tuple) {
        return std::get<position>(tuple) +
            Helper<T,position - 1>::help(tuple);
    }
};

// template metaprogramming version, specialized
template
<class T>
struct Helper<T,0>{
    static int
    help(T tuple) {
        return std::get<0>(tuple);
    }
};
// function version, not working
template
<class T, std::size_t position>
constexpr int
helper(T tuple) {
    return
        0 == position ?
            std::get<position>(tuple) + helper<T,position-1>(tuple) :
            std::get<0>(tuple);
}

template
<class T>
auto
Foo(T tuple) {
    constexpr std::size_t dimension = std::tuple_size<T>::value;
    // working version, using the helper struct
    return Helper<T,dimension - 1>::help(tuple);
    // wrong(?) version, using the constexpr helper function
    return helper<T,dimension - 1>(tuple);
}

int main() {
    std::tuple<int,int> t(1,1);
    Foo(t);
    return 0;
}
```

**My questions:**

- Is it principally wrong to try this kind of iteration during compile
  time with constexpr functions?
- If not, is it a bug in the compiler
  or how should a correct version look like?

I am totally aware that, due to the same types in the tuple (int,int,...), one could implement a similar version with vectors. But I think that the tuple version is conceptually better to my kind of problem and faster during runtime.

Comment: If you know all the elements of the tuple are the same type, why not use `std::array`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have a function template - all the code *must* be compiled out. So here:

```
template
<class T, std::size_t position>
constexpr int helper(T tuple) {
    return
        0 == position ?
            std::get<position>(tuple) + helper<T,position-1>(tuple) :
            std::get<0>(tuple);
}
```

We always compile **both** parts of the conditional (side-note: your conditional is backwards). So when `position == 0`, both the `std::get<0>(tuple)` part is compiled **and** the `std::get<0>(tuple) + helper<T, -1>(tuple)` part is compiled. But then to do that, we'd need to compile `helper<T, -2>(tuple)`. And `helper<T, -3>(tuple)`. We recursive infinitely.

Your specialization approach works because `Helper<T, 0>` just does `std::get<0>`. There is no other logic in there, so we stop. If you want to do this functionally, an easier way would be to pass the position *as an argument*. That is:

```
template <std::size_t position>
using Pos = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, position>; // to save me some typing

template <typename T>
constexpr int helper(T const& tuple, Pos<0> )
{
    return std::get<0>(tuple);
}

template <typename T, std::size_t position>
constexpr int helper(T const& tuple, Pos<position> )
{
    return std::get<position>(tuple) + helper(tuple, Pos<position - 1>{});
}
```

Here, we do the conditional via overloading - so once we get to `helper(T, Pos<0> )`, we successfully terminate the recursion.

---

In C++1z, this becomes a ton easier with fold expressions, where you can just do:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr int sum_tuple(T const& tuple) {
    return sum_tuple(tuple, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<T>::value>{});
}

template <typename T, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr int sum_tuple(T const& tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...> )
{
    return (std::get<Is>(tuple) + ... );
}
```

Comment: @JonathanWakely I like how SO's timestamp resolution isn't precise enough to show which one of us posted first.

Comment: Just for later readers: The order of the helper functions is important. One can not interchange helper(T const& tuple, Pos<position>) and helper(T const& tuple, Pos<0>).

Comment: The backwards conditional (`0 == position`) is humoristically refered as Yoda condition and is used by some coders in order to avoid accidental value assignation: `return 0 = position ...` is a noticeable error while `return position = 0 ...` is (at best case) a sneaky warning.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster What does that have anything to do with the question?

Comment: @Barry It doesn't have anything to do with the question but with your answer. I was thinking that it was worth to mention because you seemed kinda surprised to read this backwards conditional... but don't worry, in the future I will save for myself this topics even if I think that they could be useful.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster I think in this particular case it would have even been enough to write `return position ? ...` This was exactly the reason why I chose this order, but "Yoda condition" is knew to me

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster It has nothing to do with the answer either. When I said the conditional was backwards, I meant that OP flipped the true and false expressions. If `position == 0`, OP meant to do just `std::get<0>(tuple)` - but the logic is inverted.

Comment: Even now, you can do something like `int sum = 0; using expander = int[]; (void) expander {0, (sum += std::get<Is>(tuple))...}; return sum;`.

Answer (score 3):

> So my questions: Is it principally wrong to try this kind of iteration during compile time with constexpr functions?

Yes, it's wrong, as you've done it. It can be done, but you can't terminate the compile-time recursion with a run-time condition.

When you instantiate `helper<T, N>(T)` that instantiates `helper<T, N-1>(T)` which instantiates `herlper<T, N-2>(t)` and so on, with nothing to terminate the recursion.

The class template version terminates when it reaches `N==0` because of the partial specialization, but you can't partially specialize a function template.

Barry's solution works by using a second overload to terminate the recursion, so that when it reaches `0` it chooses a different function and doesn't keep instantiating the same one forever.